# How to access Google calendar in Android

Tags: android, google-api, google-calendar-api

I have followed the [reversed engineering method](http://www.developer.com/article.php/3850276) ,but it just does not support new devices such as the android 4.x

So, I tried to find an alternative. I found [this](http://code.google.com/apis/calendar/v3/getting_started.html), but it keeps changing(in beta) and it requires internet connection to access the calendar(not sure).

Would you mind telling me the current best method to add or delete an entry in google calendar in android, to support 2.0+ devices?